# should I download IE9 for the new Yahoo update

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, download

Do I have to download all other IEs since 6 to get the update 7 or higher that Yahoo is requested for their upgraded program? It looks like 8 is combined with 7 and you cannot download 7 natively, so then there is 9. Should I just download the 9?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  Windows XP **cannot** run IE9, it will only work on Vista or Windows 7.

Comment: Stop using IE. -

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to stick with IE8. Wait a while to go with IE9 as not every application is compatible with it at this point in time.